# for statement not executing

Tags: c++

I am writing a program, for homework, that will add 2 8-bit binary numbers. I am to use arrays for storage for the read binary numbers. In the function that would actually do the "addition", it will not execute the for loop. When I step through, it shows the initialization of the variable n for the loop, then it goes straight to the end of loop and exits. Here is my code:

```
for ( int n = 7; n < 0 ; n-- )
{
    if ( carry == 0 )
    {
        if ( bin1[n] == 0 )
        {
            if ( bin2[n] == 0 )
            {
                sum[n] = 0;
                carry = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                sum[n] = 1;
                carry = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ( bin2[n] == 0 )
            {
                sum[n] = 1;
                carry = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                sum[n] = 0;
                carry = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ( bin1[n] == 0 )
        {
            if ( bin2[n] == 0 )
            {
                sum[n] = 1;
                carry = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                sum[n] = 0;
                carry = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ( bin2[n] == 0 )
            {
                sum[n] = 0;
                carry = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                sum[n] = 1;
                carry = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I know this may not be the most efficient way to write this so please avoid those answers.

Comment: Hmmm...`int n = 7; n < 0` It is doing exactly what you asked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your condition is false from the start, so the loop exits immediately:

```
for ( int n = 7; n < 0 ; n-- )
```

You probably meant:

```
for ( int n = 7; n >= 0 ; n-- )
```

Comment: Attempted the change, though I didn't see the condition being wrong as max = 8 ( i know i didn't post that ), and it still jumps the body. he loop starts reading the array at subscript 7 and goes to 0.

Comment: @Bizkutz: The for loop starts with `n` at the initial value 7 and then keeps executing the body while the condition is true. If you leave the initial condition it's clearly not correct, as `n` is initially 7 so n < 0 is false. Isn't going from index 7 to 0 what you wanted?

Comment: my apologies, as I was obviously confusing myself with the condition of the for statement. The change solved my problem, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If `n` is initialized to 7, it will never be `< 0`... Your condition is wrong. Should have been `>` or `>=`.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop condition is wrong. `n` will never be less than 0. Try this instead:

```
for (int n = 7; n >= 0 ; n--)
```

Answer (score 1):

( `int n = 7; n < 0 ; n-- )`

the < is turned the wrong way. Either do:

```
( int n = 7; n > 0 ; n-- )
```

or `( int n = 0; n < 7 ; n++ )`

Comment: If n=7, it is already > 0, so wouldn't that exit the loop immediately? Notice I am using the -- operator to decrement my counter.

Comment: The loop executes `while(condition) is true` not `until(condition)`.

Comment: I was confusing the condition of the for statement. Thank you.

Comment: < means less then. so the statement you orginally had reads: keep looping as long as n is less then 0. And obviously since N starts at 7 it is greater then 0 and the statement will be false. If you turn the sign it will read: keep looping as long as n is greater then 0. And when N starts at 7 it is greater then 0 and the loop will enter.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop never executes, as 7 is not less than 0. To fix it, just write:

```
for(int n = 7; n >= 0; --n) // note: I use --n, because n-- 
{                           // creates temporary objects 
    .....                   // and makes the program slower
}
```

If doesn't work, write some `printf`s (or `cout`s if you use the iostream library) to see where is the problem